# Is it possible to set a default column format in SQLPLUS?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

Answers I have found online advise me to run the following for every column

```
column column_name format a30
```

I don't want to have to keep typing this in for every column, and every time query a different table to make it readable in my terminal.

Comment: Aside from adding lots of `column` commands in a login script, no. Have you considered switching to [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html), whose [`set sqlformat ansiconsole` might help](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/04/video-overview-of-set-sqlformat-ansiconsole/)?

Comment: Thanks Alex. No I haven't, I'll take a look.